# Wanting to print based on a string; Java

Tags: java

I'm wanting to use Jsoup to parse through some HTML code. Firstly, I want to only print out the bolded row that contains the(not really columns)headers as the HTML is formatted by rows.I want to select & print the tr tag that contains the bold style within the tag. How do I convert the bold styled tr to a Java GUI table with the bold styled tr with the td elements as the column headers? How do I reformat the document to be able to sort by columns and not rows?

I have attached the GitHub link with the Java code. I couldn't get it to pass the algorithm.

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/elec08/6f5100771485943df87a756b6f1eb09d)

Comment: Seems you have several problems. Try to ask only one issue by question. 
Post your code here. 
Anyway, think, how could `whole.equals(tr) && whole.equals(tr_end)` evaluate to `true` when `tr.equals(tr_end)` evaluate to `false` ?

Comment: I was trying to include the beginning tag of the bolded row, the content between, and the ending tag. I only want that content to print for now.